# How to get the current time stamp

Tags: matlab, time, timestamp, system

How can I  get the current local system time stamp in microseconds in MATLAB.
I need to share and record this time stamp when sending messages to another computer. How can I do this? Please help me with this.

For instance I'd like to be able to do:

```
fprintf('I am sending the first message at ....... microseconds')
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to [so]! Did you try to find a solution on the web? Your Question seems to be a bit off-topic! Please read [help/on-topic] and [help/dont-ask]!

Comment: If you need microseconds, you probably want to do a system call. You can get milliseconds from the the last entry in datevec(now), but I don't believe it is necessarily millisecond accurate.

Comment: What version of MATLAB?

Comment: `datevec(now)` is milisecond accurate. There's a few digits at 1e-12, but that's round-off and floating point precission.